# Comparing values from DataRow with a Dictionary of objects

Tags: c#, equality

I'm writing database test utils code which compares DataRow values with expected values supplied as a Dictionary (columnName, expectedColumnValue).

It works fine for many types, but for byte and short I had to add conversion code that converts the values to an Int32.

Two questions:

1. Do you have ideas how to make this code better, i.e. how to avoid the conversion? 
   For decimal and float it seems to work as they are explicitly declared as a decimal/float value. Long also works without problems.
2. If there is no other way, are there any other types apart from short and byte that I need to worry about?

Demo code below:

```
            var table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CarrierId", typeof(byte)));
            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("NotationId", typeof(short)));

            var row = table.NewRow();
            row[0] = 5;
            row[1] = 123;

            table.Rows.Add(row);

            var expected = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"CarrierId", 5},
                {"NotationId", 123},
            };

            foreach (var entry in expected)
            {
                var value = row[entry.Key];
                var expectedValue = entry.Value;

                if (value is short || value is byte)
                    value = Convert.ToInt32(value);

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Not converted: {0}", row[entry.Key].Equals(entry.Value)));
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Converted (if applicable): {0}", value.Equals(expectedValue)));

            }
```

Comment: Use the strongly typed [`Row.Field<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) extension method.

Comment: Avoid datasets/datatables/datarows like the plague.  Use custom classes and an ORM.  :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I would like to avoid passing in the types to keep it as simple as possible. Otherwise I'd need to change the code for every table that needs testing.

Comment: @dumdum - it's pretty hard to avoid tables/datasets when they are already there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the values in their expected type to the dictionary, then you should not need to do the conversion any more when comparing:

```
var expected = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "CarrierId", (byte)5 },
    { "NotationId", (short)123 },
};
```

---

When you assign an `int` number given by a constant expression (known at compile time) to a `byte` variable, C# automatically converts it to `byte`.

```
byte b = 5; // Stores a byte
```

But when you assign it to an `object` variable, C# does not know that you will be using it as a `byte` in future and threats it as an `int` by default.

```
object o = 5; // Stores an int
```

Comment: Event in this case byte b = 5; it does an implicit conversion from int to byte, check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Nick: Yes, but this probably applies only to the litteral. I guess that the produced IL code will not have any conversion.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Well if it's an int variable then it won't compile without explicit cast, try it yourself int k = 5;
            byte b = k; wont work, but this will 
            byte b = (int)k; Your answer was great, I just wanted to add a little bit to support what you are saying. You got +1 from me ;)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Olivier Jacot-Descombes's answer, you can try this code:

```
object o = 5;
var v = o;
if (v is short)
   MessageBox.Show("short");
else if (v is byte)
   MessageBox.Show("byte");
else if (v is int)
   MessageBox.Show("int");
```

Whenever you assign an `integer` literal to an `object` it is essentially int and therefore, `var` will be `int`. Therefore I would suggest to you to use casting to a type from the database not vice versa.

Comment: That's true, however, if you cast the 5 as short when assigning it to an object as Olivier suggested, then the first if evaluates to true:  object p = (short)5;
            var x = p;

Comment: @Joanna Of course, it suppose to be that way. Var variable is determined according to the real type of the right-hand type

Comment: Yes, the real type of `var` is evaluated from the static type of the expression on the right hand side of the equal sign. The type of the value in `o` makes no difference. `v` will always be an `object`. The value stored in `v`, however, will be an `int`.